Не могу тэг <a> заставить скачивать фаЙл
Проект на Next.js.
Нужно, что бы при клике на ссылку файл начинал скачиваться.
Сначала пробовал:
<a
    href={'report' in item ?
        (item as ReportType).report //http://82.97.248.11:12121/media/about_us/reports/Jan_2024.jpg
        :
        (item as DocumentType).document //http://82.97.248.11:12121/media/about_us/document/Jan_2024.jpg
    }
    download={extractFileName('report' in item ? item.report : item.document)}
    type="button"
    className={style.buttonDownload}
></a>

В результате происходит переход по ссылке, а не скачивание файла. Затем попробовал:
<a
    href={'report' in item ? 
        `data:${(item as ReportType).report}` //data:http://82.97.248.11:12121/media/about_us/reports/Jan_2024.jpg
        :
        `data:${(item as DocumentType).document}` //data:http://82.97.248.11:12121/media/about_us/docunent/Jan_2024.jpg
    }
    download={extractFileName('report' in item ? item.report : item.document)}
    type="button"
    className={style.buttonDownload}
></a>

В результате запрос блокируется браузером(но это не точно) и выдаёт сообщение как на картинке.

Девтулс показывает наличие атрибута download

import style from './List.module.scss';
import Link from 'next/link';

type ReportType = {
    id: number;
    language: number;
    name: string;
    report: string;
};

type DocumentType = {
    id: number;
    language: number;
    name: string;
    document: string;
};

type CombinedType = ReportType | DocumentType;

export default function List({
    title,
    items,
}: {
    title: string;
    items: CombinedType[];
}) {
    function removeExtension(filename: string) {
    var parts = filename.split('.');
    return parts[0];
    }

    function extractFileName(url: string) {
    // Разделим строку URL по символу '/'
    let parts = url.split('/');
    // Получим последний элемент после разделения - это имя файла
    let fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];
    return fileName;
    }

    return (
    <div className={style.list}>
        <h2 className={style.title}>{title}</h2>
        <ul className={style.listBody}>
        {items.map((item, i) => {
            return (
            <li key={item.id} className={style.item}>
                <p className={style.titleItem}>{removeExtension(item.name)}</p>
                <a
                href={
                    'report' in item
                    ? // ? `data:${(item as ReportType).report}`
                        // : `data:${(item as DocumentType).document}`
                        (item as ReportType).report
                    : (item as DocumentType).document
                }
                download={extractFileName(
                    'report' in item ? item.report : item.document
                )}
                // type="button"
                className={style.buttonDownload}
                ></a>
            </li>
            );
        })}
        </ul>
    </div>
    );
}


Ну во-первых прекратите мучать ссылку, если у вас «происходит переход по ссылке» и он успешный, значит ссылка рабочая и не надо её трогать

А во-вторых, если ваша проблема в том, что браузер показывает картинку вместо предложения её сохранить, то как минимум через девтулзы хотя бы проверьте, а атрибут download в ссылке добавляется вообще хоть какой-нибудь?

первым делом проверил, и если вы обратите внимание  на картинку которую я прикрепил, то даже насторил присваивание имени файла через этот атрибут

Ну картинка лично мне ни о чём не говорит, потому что имя файла вполне могло подтянуться из (сломанной вами) ссылки

прикрепил скрин из девтулза

И если вы вернёте ссылку в нормальное рабочее состояние без всех этих извращений с data, браузер всё равно просто показывает картинку вместо скачивания?

так точно. просто открывает ссылку. пробовал в хроме и в edge

А не перехватываются ли клики по ссылкам (а может и не только по ссылкам) каким-нибудь скриптом, который вы не упомянули?

прикрепил код компонента в вопрос

А это вполне может быть не компонент, а что-нибудь стороннее, и если вы не уверены что это может быть, то тут наверное самое время просить [mcve] — например, попытаться создать новый nextjs-проектик с нуля и посмотреть как он себя поведёт

ок, попробую и вернусь

Как я понял у Вас там base64, судя по скрину(href=“data…), вряд ли будет так работать, можете создать ObjectURL https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static это должно помочь, насколько я знаю, вечером смогу проверить

И код рендера тогда будет иной, так как это затратно, нужно делать иначе.

Попробуйте заменить протокол http на https в ссылке

а зачем писать download="имя файла" ? пишут обычно в ссылке  и всё

и ещё type="button" зачем-то там. Это же не input, зачем ему type

URL: createObjectURL()  не пойму, как я это могу использовать.  в моём распоряжении только ссылка на файл.

"И если вы вернёте ссылку в нормальное рабочее состояние без всех этих извращений с data, браузер всё равно просто показывает картинку вместо скачивания?" да.  изначально просто добавил атрибут download.

"Попробуйте заменить протокол http на https в ссылке"  не помогло

ларчик открывалсе не много с другой строноны. кому интересно можно почитать - https://macarthur.me/posts/trigger-cross-origin-download/
